# How map values in a column in a grouping by tranformation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
              'value':[2,5,4,3,2,5,4,3,1,5,4],
              'feature':['color','length','strenght','shine','ability','ability','strength','color','speed','shine','length']})
```

DataFrame:

```
id   value   feature
1      2      color
1      5      length
1      4      strenght
1      3      shine
1      2      ability
2      5      ability
2      4      strength
2      3      color
2      1      speed
2      5      shine
2      4      length
```

I want to create 6 new columns like this:

`bad` total count of `values`  1 and 2 per `id`

`normal`total count of `values` = 3   per `id`

`good` total count of v alues 4 and 5   per `id`

`not_favorable` is the % of `bad` in total sum of `bad, good and normal`

`favorable` is the % of `good` in total sum of `bad, good and normal`

`neutral` is the % of `normal` in total sum of `bad, good and normal`

Like the outuput below:

**Desidered Output 1:**

```
id      bad   normal   good    not_favorable    neutral    favorable
1        2      1       2          40%            20%         40%
2        2      1       4          28,57%         14,28%%     57,14%
```

**Desidered Output 2:**

Here I need the same output but grouping by the `feature` columns:

```
   feature      bad   normal   good    not_favorable    neutral    favorable
    color        1      1       0          50            50%         0%
    length       0      0       2          0%            0%          100%
    strength     0      0       2          0%            0%          100%
    shine        0      1       1          0%            50%         50%
    ability      1      0       1          50%           0%          50%
    speed        1      0       0          100%          0%          0%
```

Important:  In the real dataset I can have `NaN` values.  If it happens I just want to ignore the `NaN` like:

```
1
2
5
NaN
```

There are 3 values to working with.

I am having a hard time doing this.  I've been trying grouping by but the aggregation with conditionals is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# using pd.cut categorize the values into good, bad, normal
# and store result in status

df['status']=pd.cut(df['value'],bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5],
       labels=['bad',"bad",'normal',"good","good"],
       ordered=False,
       precision=0).astype('string')
```

```
# pivot on id, and take the count, and store result in df2
df2=df.pivot_table(index=['id'], columns='status', values='value', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)

# divide each value with the sum of the row and calculate percentage
df2[['not_favorable', 'favorable','neutral']] = round(df2.div(df2.sum(1),0),2).mul(100).astype(str)+'%'

# reset index 
out=df2.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
out
```

```
    id  bad     good    normal  not_favorable   favorable   neutral
0   1   2   2   1   40.0%   40.0%   20.0%
1   2   1   4   1   17.0%   67.0%   17.0%
```

```
# same as above, the only difference being the creation of the df2
# which is now based on feature

df2=df.pivot_table(index=['feature'], columns='status', values='value', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
df2[['not_favorable', 'favorable','neutral']] = round(df2.div(df2.sum(1),0),2).mul(100).astype(str)+'%'
out=df2.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

out
```

```
feature     bad     good    normal  not_favorable   favorable   neutral
0   ability     1.0     1.0     0.0     50.0%   50.0%   0.0%
1   color   1.0     0.0     1.0     50.0%   0.0%    50.0%
2   length  0.0     2.0     0.0     0.0%    100.0%  0.0%
3   shine   0.0     1.0     1.0     0.0%    50.0%   50.0%
4   speed   1.0     0.0     0.0     100.0%  0.0%    0.0%
5   strength    0.0     2.0     0.0     0.0%    100.0%  0.0%
```